# mod_rewrite logs show what's expected but still get 404?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I am trying to redirect the following from my user directory the follow:

```
/              > index.php?module=home
/MODULE/       > index.php?module=MODULE
/MODULE/ACTION > index.php?module=MODULE&action=ACTION
```

These are my rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite to home page.
#   Input:
#   Output: index?module=home
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?module=home [L,QSA,NC]

# Redirects to a module
#   Input:  MODULE/
#   Output: index.php?module=MODULE
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?module=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Redirects to a module with the specified action
#   Input:  MODULE/ACTION/
#   Output: index.php?module=MODULE&action=ACTION
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Just I am always getting a 404.

The logs show me what I am expecting:

```
[perdir /home/james/public_html/mysite/] rewrite 'user/login' -> 'index.php?module=user&action=login', referer: http://localhost/~james/mysite/
[perdir /home/james/public_html/mysite/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /home/james/public_html/mysite/index.php, referer: http://localhost/~james/mysite/
```

It's correctly rewriting to the the desired URL and it's adding the user directory so why the 404?

---

From the access log what file it's failing to find:

```
"GET /~james/mysite/user/login HTTP/1.1" 404 1130 "http://localhost/~james/mysite/"
```

Comment: Can you see apache access log and see for what file it returned 404?

Comment: @D.Kasipovic I've added it to the end of the question.

Comment: As I can see, /user/login is not being redirected, but /user/login/ should be?

Comment: I tried both. `/user/login/` doesn't work either. Shouldn't the rule not care about a trailing `/` because of the `/?` in the pattern. The access log is slightly different when the trailing slash is present. The code's `404 983` instead of the above `404 1130`. I'm not sure of the difference that implies.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding the following:

```
RewriteBase /~james/mysite/
```

Weird how it resolves the URL correctly but returns 404. Maybe someone smarter than me could shine more light on the matter.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I've lost 3 hours figuring out why without any clue before reading your solution...